# How to implement autosave in flutter textfield similliraly like in major ides on desktop?

Tags: android, flutter

How to can I implement a callback that fires after every few seconds or when user stop typing in TextField ?

Or is it performant to just implement in onChanged callback directly ?

Answer (score 0):

input Field onChanged gives the input value when ever user types in, So you may use onChnaged callback function to save the input, like below,

```
TextFormField(
                controller: _nameController,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  saveData();
                },
                initialValue: widget.user.userName,
                onSaved: (val) {
                  widget.user.userName = val;
                },
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.length > 3 ? null : 'Full name is invalid',
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Full Name',
                  hintText: 'Enter your full name',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  isDense: true,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Actually I want to store the value of textfield in database, but is it performant to store on onChanged callback ? If not how I can implement a callback that can fire smartly based on user activity or some time frame ?